# Linux & C: 'write()' does not write anything to file

Tags: c, linux, file-io

I have a simple task to accomplish with this routine where, all it has to do is, open the file, append data from a buffer & close.
I am using 'open' & 'write' for that purpose on a linux machine. Although the return code after 'write()' is positive, the file size does not increase and it is always empty. I ma pulling my hair to figure out what the issue with the below code. Thought some fresh eyes can shed some light.

```
#define BIT_Q_FILE  ".\\bitq.dat"

int BQWrite(void *p)
{
int fd ;
int rc = -1 ;

fd = open(BIT_Q_FILE, O_RDWR | O_APPEND ) ;

if (fd < 0)
    return -1;


memset(&BITQBuff,0,sizeof(typeBITQFile));
memcpy(&BITQBuff.pBitQueue,p,sizeof(typeBITQueue));

rc = write(fd, &BITQBuff,sizeof(typeBITQFile)) ;

close(fd) ;

if(rc!=sizeof(typeBITQFile))
{
    return -1;
}

rc = sizeof(typeBITQueue);

return rc ;
}
```

Comment: can you try `fflush(fd)` and see if that helps? `close` flushes the buffers, but just covering all bases. Also, what is the value that `rc` contains after the `write` call?

Comment: Print the value you are getting from the sizeof operator.

Comment: @Levon, `fflush()` operates on `FILE *`, not on low level descriptors.

Comment: Does the last modification date of the file change after the write operation?

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks Hristo, I suspected an unflushed buffer .. learned something new.

Comment: I had tried 'fflush()', but did not help much. When I printed the values returned, they all looked accurate. 'write()' returned exact amount of bytes that I was trying to write. 
Humm, I didn't check the modification date. I can't rely on it because the clock is not reliable because, this is on an embedded platform and every time I reboot system, it resets to UTC time. 
Besides, solution provided by Zack helped.
Thank you guys for a quick response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got your problem right here:

```
#define BIT_Q_FILE  ".\\bitq.dat"
```

You've hit a trifecta of Windows-to-Unix porting gotchas:

- The directory separator on Unix is `/`, not `\`.
- But Unix is perfectly happy to let you put `\` in the middle of a file name.  (The *only* bytes — and I really mean *bytes*, not characters — that cannot appear in a pathname component are those with the values 0x2F and 0x00.)
- Unix is also perfectly happy to let a file name *begin* with a dot; however, by default `ls` does not print any file names that begin with a dot.

So you are expecting data to be written to a file named `bitq.dat` in the current directory, but it is actually being written to a file named `.\bitq.dat`, still in the current directory. That file is hidden by default, so it looks like the data is disappearing into thin air.  `ls -a` will reveal the hidden file, and `rm .\\bitq.dat` will delete it.  To fix your code, just change the define to

```
#define BIT_Q_FILE "bitq.dat"
```

It is not necessary to put a leading `./` on the path passed to `open`.

This may not be the only problem with your code, but I don't see anything else obviously wrong.  If you need more help, please post a new question with a *complete*,  *minimal* test program that people can compile and run for themselves.

Comment: thanks. This was exactly what was happening. Very good catch.
Thank you. It really helped.

Answer (score 4):

Try change

```
#define BIT_Q_FILE  ".\\\bitq.dat"
```

to

```
#define BIT_Q_FILE  "./bitq.dat"
```

Comment: Or even just "bitq.dat".  Also, check the working directory.  There is a file named `.\bitq.dat` there.  Because its name starts with a `.` it is a hidden file.

Comment: Thanks. Just "bitq.bat" helped.
Yes, now I see '.\bitq.bat' file in that folder. How can I get rid of it. The system command 'rm' does not help. The message I get when I try that is as follows:
'rm: Cannot remove '.bitq.bat': NO such file or directory'
But I can see that file when I do 'll' or 'ls -la'.
Any thoughts?

Comment: @GregInozemtsev Greg, even the -f & -fr options did not help!

Comment: You need to type `rm .\\bitq.bat`, with _two_ backslashes.  The shell treats backslash as an escape character (with, alas, entirely different _meaning_ than C does, but the effect for purpose of this problem is the same).  Another way to do it is `rm -i .*bitq.bat` -- this is the more general tactic for getting rid of files whose names contain weird characters you can't type.